# Shall i use "saw" or "have seen" in this sentence?

Tags: tense

A: Do you know her

B: I saw/ have seen her a few times but I never spoke to her.

Comment: You can use either one. It depends what you want to say, which is why there is both a past simple and a present perfect in English. You might want to click on those two tags and so some reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction would be `have + past participle` in such cases.

> I've seen her ...

Here, "I saw..." would depict a distant past opposite to '..have seen' which is a recent past.

Both construction would work depending on what you want to say.

Comment: Well, actually a "few times" event, as OP stated. Simple past works fine.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock the stroke (/) confused me. I thought the OP is not including '..a few times' with 'saw'. Changed

Comment: I don't think simple past works very well in response the question "Do you know her?"  It would be better suited to "Did you know her?"

Comment: That depends! In fact the straightforward answer could be, "No, I don't!" And, that's the reason, if you see my unedited answer, I tried to describe that it's a 'one time event' not proper to the question (i.e. **in that context**). But Brian provoked me to change it! :P @TRomano

Comment: I think the question to ask is not whether the thing is *distant* or *recent*, but whether it impinges upon the present. Since the question is about one's current knowledge, it invites a reply that couches the facts with reference to the present: "Do you *know* her? *I've seen* her on several occasions but ..."

Comment: If the respondent wanted to distance his knowledge from the present, then he could use the simple past:  "I *met* her years ago" and then continue on with reference to the present: "...but *have* never *spoken* with her *since*." or with reference to the past:  "... but never *spoke* with her *afterwards*."

Comment: Exactly, in the context of 'current knowledge', using 'saw' didn't sound okay to me. @TRomano